# Cambiar el CommandTimeout a un query de WebMatrix Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Alguien sabe como aumentar el CommandTimeout en una consulta usando la clase [Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/gg569069(v%3Dvs.111)) de WebMatrix, internamente crea un objeto sqlCommand con un tiempo default de 30 segundos.

Mi código es similar al siguiente:

```
var db = Database.Open("Bdd1");
var result = db.Query("SELECT x, y,z FROM FuncionQueTarda");
```

La función tarda poco mas de 1 minuto, y obtiene información de varias bases de datos y las une en un resultado.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: podrias mirar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471744/webmatrix-database-query-with-custom-commandtimeout

Comment: Gracias @Gerardo fué mi primer intento, pero el ConnectionTimeout es diferente al CommandTimeout

Comment: Si leí mal, ya he borrado el comentario. Has probado ha meter en la cadena de conexion el parametro `Timeout=XX`?

Comment: Gracias @Tegito123 la pregunta tiene 3 años y la conclusión es "lo hice de esta forma por que no encontré solución", así que me atreví a preguntarlo de nuevo en este foro.

Comment: Aqui parece que tratan el tema y han encontrado alguna solución. https://forums.asp.net/t/1293504.aspx?CommandTimeout+

Comment: Vi el vínculo que me mandaste @Gerardo , ayudenme a entender esto, está modificando el event Handler del SqlDataSource1_Selecting dice que lo hace en tiempo de diseño, ¿Cómo se hace? : "I did this in studio by using design mode and double clicking the sqldatasource, which gave me the protected sub, then added the timeout."